# heuristic algorithm for non-metric symmetric TSP on a complete weighted undirected graph with 100-1000 vertices

Tags: traveling-salesman

any (heuristic) algorithm for non-metric symmetric TSP that works on a complete weighted undirected graph with 100-1000 vertices?

Comment: If it respects neither triangle inequality nor symmetry, it is inapproximable.

Comment: hi @KennethKho, it has symmetry (weighted undirected), just not following triangle inequality (can have cost(AC) > cost(AB)+cost(BC))

Comment: Sorry I messed up. Does this match the requirements of your problem instead? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115077/can-non-metric-tsp-be-approximated-within-some-non-constant-value